# virtual MySql server with mounted RAID array

Tags: mysql, permissions, ubuntu, virtualisation

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server with an 18TB RAID array.  I am running virtual servers on the server using Wok/Kimchi and am wondering if it is reasonable to run a MySQL virtual server and set the data directory to run on the RAID that is mounted by sshfs or samba?  Alternatively, should I just make a large virtual machine instance and keep the data in the default /var/lib/mysql location and then do backups of the database to the RAID array?  I would think it is best to keep the data in a "real" location on the RAID but perhaps if that RAID is unmounted for some reason my database will be corrupted.

For testing I tried setting the data directory to the mounted RAID and ran into all sorts of ownership issues despite several different ways of doing this that I found online.  The one that sort of works is to mount the RAID using sshfs using solution 2 from here, but that is maybe not best from a security perspective:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326883/owner-of-sshfs-mounted-directory-with-777-permission-cant-open-it-no-acl-no-s

I then followed this guide to mv /var/lib/mysql to the mounted RAID array:  http://www.vacilando.org/article/moving-mysql-data-files-virtualbox-shared-folder.  It threw file permission/ownership errors but appears to have moved the folder and mysql is running and I can create databases.  I could never get anything to work with a samba mount because of ownership issues.  Also, trying to rsync the /var/lib/mysql directory to the RAID never worked and I had to use mv despite it also giving ownership errors with the sshfs mount.

I am quite new to this and maybe overthinking something here, which is why maybe I should make the large (a few TB should be plenty) storage allocation for a virtual machine and let mysql store its data in the default /var/lib/mysql directory.

Comment: Perhaps you are not I/O-bound, so the performance of samba or sshfs does not matter?